# SFSafariViewController displays empty screen for any URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios10, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am trying to display a URL using `SFSafariViewController`. Here is my code: (`topmostController` points to the, yes, topmost controller)

```
SFSafariViewController *safariVc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
[[UIViewController topmostController] presentViewController:safariVc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Regardless of the URL that I try to present, I'm getting this:

[image]

The address bar is blank and unresponsive, refresh button doesn't do anything, all the bottom buttons are disabled, there is no page, and the top bar layout is messed up.

I've tried multiple times with multiple domains but it's always the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The issue is probably the implementation of `[UIViewController topmostController]`. Can you post that? In my experience, this happens when you try to present on a view controller you can't really present on (as far as the system knows)

Comment: @Dima as it's just a helper that returns the topmost controller. if it wasn't working the safari controller wouldn't be displayed at all. it is returning the correct view controller (i've put a breakpoint and verified)

Comment: That's actually not quite right. I've had this happen before when trying to present on a child view controller that was shown in a custom fashion in a container (ie not technically presented). The presentation seemed to work, but the result was identical to your screenshot. Presenting from the container made it work fine. Are you trying to present on a contained view controller? In any case, the code you pasted has no problem so the issue has to be somewhere else.

Answer (score 8):

Swift 4.2:

```
let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: URL)
view.window?.rootViewController?.present(safariViewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this method.

1, Check `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow`

2, Does the source ViewController exist on that keyWindow?

3, If it does not exist, execute `makeKey()` for that source window.

Comment: could you post a full example how to use it?